# Razor pages - redirect to route

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm using custom routes in Razor Pages on .net core 2.2 based on microsoft documentation

```
AddRazorPagesOptions(options => { options.Conventions.AddPageRoute ...
```

and Im also using default authentication.

When user comes to the page that need authentication, he is redirected to page "Login" with query string

```
ReturnUrl={routeOfPreviousPage}
```

as default auth does.

Now after loggin user in I'm trying to redirect him to that route he wanted to go to.

Whatever "RedirectTo...." I use I keep on geting error

> System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values

I tried

- RedirectToRoute
- RedirectToPage

Is there any way to redirect to page based on route name?

---

Based on comment:

I have convetions like this:

```
options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/foo", "foo-pl");
options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/foo");
```

and the value of

> routeOfPreviousPage

is

> foo-pl

so this is the one I think it should hit.

Comment: You need to show some actual code. What `PageRouteModelConvention` did you add? What is the value of `routeOfPreviousPage`? What route do you think should be matched?

Comment: @MikeBrind I added code you asked for to the question